# Check if two numbers are close to each other

Tags: c

I want to check if two numbers are within a range of each other, by a given value.

```
boolean withinRange(double input1, double input2, double deviation){

//input1 will always be the biggest value
  if(input1 > input2){
    //do nothing
  } else if(input1 < input2) {
    double temp = input1;
    input1 = input2;
    input2 = temp;
  } else if(input1 == input2){
    return true;
  }

  if(input2 + deviation < input1 - deviation < input2){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

So inputs like withinRange(2,3,2) should be true, but withinRange(1,4,2) should be false. I know the code is wrong, but I am not sure howto solve it. It is coded in Arduino, so very simular to C.

Comment: what is `afvigelse`

Comment: Calculate difference of `input1` and `input2` (considering sign) and compare it with `deviation` (i.e. it should be `<= deviation`).

Comment: @KamiKaze It's "deviation" in Danish.

Comment: Sorry I will fix the translation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
if(input2 + deviation < input1 - deviation < input2){
```

Expressions in C are not the same as mathematical equations.  This does *not* check if `input1 - deviation` is between `input2 + deviation` and `input2`.  With implicit parenthesis in place, it looks like this:

```
if(((input2 + deviation) < (input1 - deviation)) < input2){
```

This first checks if `(input2 + deviation) < (input1 - deviation)` is true.  Then the result of this comparison (either 0 or 1) is compared against `input2`.

The proper way to write the above expression would be:

```
if (((input2 + deviation) < (input1 - deviation)) && ((input1 - deviation) < input2)) {
```

But this still isn't doing what you intend.  Since you normalize `input1` to be greater than `input2`, all you need is this:

```
if ((input1 - input2) <= deviation) {
```

Note the use of `<=` to allow a difference of exactly `deviation` to be acceptable.

Comment: Hmm, when I test your last line of code you suggested, I get wrong results. 

withinRange(3, 5, 1) gives false, and it should be false. 
withinRange(5, 3, 2) gives false, but should be true. 

I kept the code that makes input1 greater than input2, and replaced the comparing code with your:

    if ((input1 - input2) < afvigelse) {

Comment: @Bassusour If the exact difference of `afvigelse` is acceptable, change the condition from `<` to `<=`.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

This is usually done like so, quite simply:

```
bool withinRange(double input1, double input2, double deviation)
{
  return fabs(input1 - input2) <= deviation;
}
```

Note that the C Boolean type is called `bool`. I edited to make the answer include the boundary, that is more intuitive so it might make it easier to verify.

Basically the absolute value of a subtraction is the distance between the two terms, so we compute that and compare it against the limit.

Answer (score 1):

```
double out = num1 - num2;
if(out < 0) out *= -1;
if(out <= deviation)
    return true;
else return false;
```

This should work. You can also try to check which number is bigger and then swap them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if a number is in the range of the another number +/- range :

```
boolean withinRange(double input1, double input2, double deviation)
{
    return (input1 - deviation <= input2 && input2 <= input1 + deviation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i will just say:

```
public bool checkInRange(float a, float b, double deviation)
{
    if (a < b)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = a - b;
        a = a - b;
    }

    return ((a - b) <= deviation || a == b);
}
```